# Cannot change IIS 7.5 ASP Classic timeout after IIS error

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm working on a problem with timeouts with an ASP Classic site under IIS 7.5 on Win2008R2.  I set the time-out to 1 minute so that I could test and everything was working fine. I tried to set it to 5 seconds to speed up testing, but received an error saying time-out cannot be less than 1 minute, and the time-out change was canceled.

Now IIS manager says the timeout is 1 minutes, but Session says it's 20 minutes.  Nothing i do will change the timeout that is in Session.  I've changed the time-out and saved it, tried restarting IIS, removed the application from IIS and added it back, but the timeout is still 20 minutes.

Does anyone know how I can reset this timeout?

Edit:  I've checked applicationHost.config and it looks OK.

```
<location path="Default Web Site/CostBrad">
    <system.webServer>
        <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true">
            <session timeout="00:01:00" />
        </asp>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</location>
```

Comment: You might be able to fix any "bad" data in IIS's store by editing the `applicationHost.config` file directly.

Comment: Thx vcsJones, but i tried that.  this is in applicationHost.config:

    <location path="Default Web Site/CostBrad">
        <system.webServer>
            <asp scriptErrorSentToBrowser="true">
                <session timeout="00:01:00" />
            </asp>
            <security>
                <authentication>
                    <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
                    <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
                </authentication>
            </security>
        </system.webServer>
    </location>

Answer (score 0):

A Reboot fixed the problem....